# Save only the contents of php array to file

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$urls_array`, how do I only save the contents and not anything else into a file?

INPUT:

```
Array (
  [0] => "http://google.com"
  [1] => "http://facebook.com"
  [2] => "http://yahoo.com"
)
```

OUTPUT:

```
http://google.com
http://facebook.com
http://yahoo.com
```

I tried using `json_encode($urls_array)` and `serialize()` and `print_r()`, but nothing gave me the clean result I wanted. Any help?

Comment: what about file_put_contents?

Comment: tried that too but it basically saves all the array stuff "Array([0]=>" and not just the URL

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried file_put_contents?

```
file_put_contents('filename', join("\n", $your_array));
```

The above has only a small problem: if your array is big, it will be converted to a long string before being written to the file as a whole. To avoid this memory intensive operation, loop through the array and write each item to the file sequentially:

```
if(($f = fopen("filename","w")) !== FALSE) {
  array_walk($your_array, function($item) use($f) { fwrite($f, $item . "\n"); });

  // or, with an implicit loop
  // foreach($your_array as $item) fwrite($f, $item . "\n");
}
```

Comment: this works!! guess there's magic with the join("\n") part which I didn't use earlier... genius thanks!

Comment: @NoIdeaForName: I didn't edit anything in my original code. Look at the edit history

Answer (score 2):

try this code its 100% working...

```
  <?php
    $data=array("http://google.com","http://facebook.com","http://yahoo.com");
    $fp = fopen('file.txt', 'w');
    foreach($data as $key => $value){
   fwrite($fp,$value."\t");
  }
    fclose($fp);
     ?>
```

Comment: OP only wants the array elements in his file, not the array structure.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
file_put_contents('/path/to/file', implode("\n", $urls_array));
```

Here are the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
<?php
  $arr=array("ABC","DEF","GHI");
  $fp=fopen("test.txt","w+");
  foreach($arr as $key => $value){
   fwrite($fp,$value."\t");
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$myArray = Array(0 => "http://google.com", 1 => "http://facebook.com", 2 => "http://yahoo.com");
foreach($myArray as $value){
    file_put_contents("text.txt", $value."\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
?>
```

The main benifit of `file_put_contents` is that it's equivalent calling `fopen()` + `fwrite()` + `fclose()`, so for simple tasks like this, it can be very useful.

You can find it's manual -> [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).